# Accessing POST REST API in mulesoft

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-esb

I am trying to consume RESTAPI in MULE, endpoint I am trying to access is type POST. How can I set JSON payload while sending request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the body of an HTTP request from Mule is the `payload` of the message. You can use the `Transform Message` component, or the `Set Payload` component to set the payload before the HTTP request.